# Sort alphanumeric excel file from highest to lowest using python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe

Below is my excel file I want to sort from highest to lowest

```
        A                             B
1) Tales:2                    Transport for London.....
2) Trump:30                   Roseanne Barr Actor leavin..... 
3) HIV:4                      Americas Transport for London........
```

Above are some entries from excel file. Tales:2 is at the A1 point Trump:40 is at the A2 point and Hiv:4 is at the A3 point. I want it sorted from highest to lowest. For Example Trump:30 should be on first place because it has the highest number that is 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read data into a `pandas` dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
```

Calculate sorted indices via extracted numeric data and `pd.Series.argsort`:

```
indices = df['A'].str.split(':').str[-1].astype(int).argsort()
```

Then apply indices to your dataframe, reversing for highest first:

```
df = df.iloc[indices[::-1]]
```

Comment: Please answer my following question also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50618565/find-repeated-words-in-a-excel-column-and-sort-it-according-to-number-of-occuren

Comment: ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer                                             I get this error while running your suggested code can you please help me out

Comment: I guess this error is because length of A is less than length of B in the excel file